# Enable PDO module on CENTOS 6.9 using EasyApache4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, centos6

I have installed `7.1.7-1.1.1.cpanel` and `7.0.21-1.1.1.cpanel` on my VPS server running on Centos 6.9 using EasyApache4. I have a laravel API and an angular4 app that I want to run on the server but I am having problems getting PHP to run properly. After installing the site using git I get an error;

> could not find driver (SQL: select * from `site_menu_placements` where
> `active` = 1)

I have checked error_log and I see the following which is not making much sense to me;

```
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mbstring.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_firebird.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_firebird.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_informix.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_informix.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_mssql.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_mssql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_oci.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_oci.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_oci8.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_oci8.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_odbc.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_odbc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pdo_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mbstring.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I think the error corresponds to not having `php_pdo_mysql.dll` running properly. I have checked phpinfo() and see that the main php.ini file is located at `/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc` I have tried to load the PDO modules in this file but with no effect even when I have;

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=mysql.so
```

When I look on the phpinfo() page I can see that there is a section called 'PDO' but in this section I see just sqlite in the PDO drivers row. I believe I should see mysql as well.

When I run `php artisan migrate` via ssh I get the following errors;

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException] could not find driver
>
> [PDOException] could not find driver

I think the package that's supposed to contain the pdo mysql driver is `ea-php71-php-pdo-7.1.7-1.1.6.cpanel.x86_64` I have used `rpm -ql ea-php71-php-pdo-7.1.7-1.1.6.cpanel.x86_64` to find out where it is installed and I get the following;

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so
```

So the pdo_mysql is missing.

Comment: About error on `*.dll` file, I think on linux machine files needed to load is `*.so` file, the `*.dll` file just for windows, you can ignore it. Have you restart apache service after changing the configuration?

Comment: In WHM I click on `Restart Services > HTTP Server (Apache)` after using editing the MultiPHP INI Editor. I think this affects all accounts? I can't edit the file `/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc`. It is read-only

Comment: Oh, just seeing this line on your error log `[22-Jul-2017 00:57:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so'  shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`, It seems pdo_mysql still not installed. You should enable the php extension on your EasyApache. May be this link can helps: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/How+to+Locate+and+Install+a+PHP+Version+or+Extension

Comment: I see that Package ea-php71-php-pdo-7.1.7-1.1.6.cpanel.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: I see that there is no module for mysql in /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules so it is missing. Has it been installed somewhere else?

Comment: It looks like I am missing this file; /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so How do I install it?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions:

**Step-1:** Run on command line `pecl install pdo`

**Step-2:** **if it is already installed just edit `/etc/php.ini`**

**Step-3:** Add the following lines

```
; Extension PDO
extension=pdo.so
```

**2nd Way :**

First install php-mysql

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

then enable the module

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
```

and restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope it will helpful.

Comment: This fails at the end. I get this error at the very bottom; `/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function â€˜pdo_dbh_newâ€™:
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1413: error: â€˜zend_class_entryâ€™ has no member named â€˜default_propertiesâ€™
make: *** [pdo_dbh.lo] Error 1`